# Intel® Server Board S1200SPL - Xeon with IGP Required?

Tags: intel, xeon

According to the Intel ARK page, it indicates that this board has integrated graphics:

http://ark.intel.com/products/88263

Does this mean I can put an Intel Xeon processor in it that doesn't come processor graphics built in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the motherboard has integrated graphics support, then you can use *either* processors with *or* without integrated graphics. See the [compatibility list for this motherboard](http://ark.intel.com/products/88263/Intel-Server-Board-S1200SPL#@compatibility). But if you use a processor without integrated graphics, you must also provide your own video card and the onboard video port will not work.

If the motherboard *does not* have integrated graphics support, then you can use only processors *without* integrated graphics. Compare to the [compatibility list for a similar board without integrated graphics](http://ark.intel.com/products/88264/Intel-Server-Board-S1200SPO#@compatibility).